# Убрать rel="canonical"

Tags: php, joomla

Есть код:

```
public function addLink($href, $rel) {
    if ($rel == 'canonical') {
        $document =& JFactory::getDocument();

        $document->addHeadLink($href, 'canonical', 'rel');
    } else {
        $this->links[$href] = array(
            'href' => $href,
            'rel'  => $rel
        );
    }
}
```

Не получается убрать `rel="canonical"`: либо убивает всю ссылку в `<head></head>`, либо остается пустой `rel=" "`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как корректно поправить код? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Использовать в templates/index.php, удалит в head все ссылки со значением canonical.

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
 foreach ( $doc->_links as $k => $array ) {
 if ( $array['relation'] == 'canonical' ) {
 unset($doc->_links[$k]);
 }
 }
```